# wordpress remove where clause in taxonomy page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

My site has installed woocommerce. When I visit taxonomy page, the below SQL is executed

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 

FROM wp_posts  

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 

WHERE 1=1  
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (90) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'product')
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'expired' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','catalog')) )  
AND wp_posts.post_password = '' 

GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Can I remove the following where clause

```
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','catalog')) )
```

The reason I wanna do this is because I want to display post & page results together.

**UPDATE 1**

The SQL statement above only display product result only as there is a WHERE clause which filter out post and page result. Therefore, I want to know if there is any hook to remove that particular WHERE clause statement so that the result includes post, page and product.

Comment: What's stopping you from removing it and seeing if it works?

Comment: the current result shows product only. the result should include post and page too. maybe my question wasn't clear enough. i will edit the question now. @Howlin